# DOM not being manipulated from inside a function that is being triggered properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this function to validate that all form fields and check boxes in a form are filled out. The script automatically disables the submit button and then watches for the moment at which it can be re-enabled. My `debugger` statements are landing me in all of the proper places, but for some reason, the DOM element is not being updated. I'm sure I am just making a stupid mistake, but can't seem to find a solution. Thank you in advance for any help!

Specifically looking at this section:

```
if (status === 'enable') {
          btn.removeAttr('disabled');
          btn.removeClass('disabled');
        } else {
          btn.prop('disabled', true);
          btn.addClass('disabled');
        }
```

Here is the whole script below.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      validateInput();

      $('.validate').keyup(function(event){
        validateInput();
      });

      $('[type=checkbox]').click(function(event){
        validateInput();
      });

      function validateInput() {
        var valid = 0;
        var checkBox = $('[type=checkbox]');
        var inputFields = $('input.validate');
        var inputLength = inputFields.length + checkBox.length;

        inputFields.each(function() {
          if($(this).val() !== '') {
            valid++ ;
          }
        });

        checkBox.each(function() {
          if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            valid++ ;
          }
        });

        if(valid === inputLength) {
          updateBtnStatus('enable')
        } else {
          updateBtnStatus('disable')
        }
      }

      function updateBtnStatus(status) {
        var btn = $('input[type="submit"]');
        if (status === 'enable') {
          btn.removeAttr('disabled');
          btn.removeClass('disabled');
        } else {
          btn.prop('disabled', true);
          btn.addClass('disabled');
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Try replacing `btn.removeAttr('disabled');` with `btn.prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: @Rayon - No dice. We get into the state just fine, but no matter what we call on the `btn` object, it doesn't update the DOM.

Comment: Give me a fiddle to play with...

Comment: @Rayon - I'm starting to think it might have something to do with the environment I'm using. Rails 5 + Turbolinks + Materialize. Some weird stuff happening.

Comment: @uonlyYOLOonce - returns the expected button object